# Why doesn't a counter update in while loop with readLines in R?

Tags: r

In R, why doesn't a counter update in while loop with readLines?. For example, if I run the following code, x and y output 10 at the end:

```
x <- 0
y <- 0
while(x < 10){
  x <- x + 1
  y <- y + 1
}
x
y
```

However, a file named test.txt that contains the following:

```
line one 
line two 
line three
```

and using the following code, the counter doesn't update:

```
textFile <- file("test.txt", open="r")
x <- 0
while(length(line <- readLines(textFile)) > 0){
  x <- x + 1
}
close(textFile)
x
```

Why does x output 1 instead of 3?

Comment: Check `textFile <- file("test.txt", open="r"); readLines(textFile)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `readLines()` is not reading the file in one line at a time.  It reads all of the file, unless you supply the `n=` argument, in which case it will only read a certain number of lines before stopping.  Do note, that even if you read just one line, and then call `readLines()` again it will start from the beginning of the file.